# Pass Sharepoint List Filter Value to Content Query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, content-query-web-part

I have a Sharepoint List Filter and want to connect it to a Content Query.
I tried to use variables like `[PageFilterValue: MyFilter]` but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we cannot connect the list filter web part and content query web part.

And we also cannot pass the List Filter Value from list filter web part to content query web part.

Because the content query web part only gets the filters from the columns in the sites or only in one list.